# Desctructure all the values from within an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to set state in react with a response from the backend as below. The response is stored in `result`.

```
const [object,setObjectState] = useState()

axios.post(`api`, { withCredentials: true })
     .then( res => {
            const result = res.data; //result : {id :  1, name : firstName}
            setObjectState({result})
    }
```

Setting the state like above `setState({result}` sets the state of `object` as `{ result :{id :  1, name : firstName}}`

How can I set the state of `object` as `{id :  1, name : firstName}`, without explicitly destructuring the `result` object?

I am aware that we can extract the values individually from `result` and then create a new object for `setObjectState`. But in my real use case `result has too many values inside it and I don't want to touch the code in case back-end sends new values.

Comment: Why can't we simply do `setObjectState(result)` ?

Comment: because it sets a variable called "result" and nests the values inside it, which is not what I wanted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like with spread Operator.
This would spread the data inside `result` and set that as state.

```
const [object,setObjectState] = useState()

axios.post(`api`, { withCredentials: true })
     .then( res => {
            const result = res.data; //result : {id :  1, name : firstName}
            setObjectState({...result})
    }
```

Comment: Oh sorry my bad. I missed out the braces.

Answer (score 1):

[Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is here for rescue.

if you want to persist previous state as well (which is a normal case):

```
axios.post(`api`, { withCredentials: true })
     .then( res => {
            const result = res.data; //result : {id :  1, name : firstName}
            setObjectState({...object, ...result})
    }
```

if you don't want to persist previous state (I don't know why :))

```
axios.post(`api`, { withCredentials: true })
     .then( res => {
            const result = res.data; //result : {id :  1, name : firstName}
            setObjectState({...result})
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for completing the answer with more context around setState.